# Python: How to get unspecified argument names (*args) inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function below receives dictionaries as arguments.

```
def func(*args):
    #print names of arguments that will be passed into the function

> d1, d2 = {...}, {...}
> func(d1, d2)
> ['d1', 'd2']
```

I tried many things related to the inspect module but I could only get "*args" as an output.

How can I get the name of the input dictionaries?

Cheers!

Comment: You can't get at those names. There might not be any names if called like this: `func({},{})`

Comment: You rarely ever need the variable names, what are you trying to do with them?

Comment: If you want the names of the arguments you need to explicitly pass in keyword arguments like `func(k1 = 100, k2 = 200)`. Then use `def func(**kwargs):`

Comment: @Sayse Yes, I know it is weird :) Let's say, there is one script that produces dictionaries with specific names like "xxx_dict", "yyy_dict". The function above receives those dictionaries as input and makes its process based on the strings "xxx", "yyy" etc.

Comment: @MarkM yes, this would ease this, but I cannot pass those dictionaries in keywords.

Comment: You should make an [mcve] about that, thats the real question you should be asking about

Comment: This looks like you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please add a minimal reproducible example like @Sayse said, especially explain what you need those names for.

Comment: This is not how the relationship between objects and names works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to pass a tuple containing an identifier in with your dictionaries.

```
def func(*args):

    for x in args:
        print(x[1])

d1 = {...}
d2 = {...}

func((d1, 'd1'), (d2, 'd2'))
```

Another would be to add an identifying key to your dictionary like this

```
def func(*args):

    for x in args:
        print(x['title'])

d1 = {...}
d1['title'] = 'd1'
d2 = {...}
d2['title'] = 'd2'

func(d1, d2)
```